# Extract subset from python list using comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the foll. list (toy example presented here):

```
rasters = ['A','A.txt','B','B.txt']
```

I want to remove the .txt files, so doing this:

```
ras = [x for x in enumerate(rasters) if len(os.path.splitext(x)[1]) > 0]
```

However, I get this error: `*** AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rfind'`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate`?!

Comment: I get error if i remove enumerate as well

Comment: Not in the example you've given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate(rasters)` returns a list of `(index, element)` pairs. You're passing each element of that list to `os.path.splitext`, which expects a string.

You need to make sure you only give the element, not the tuple containing the element and its index, to `splitext`. In practice this means projecting the second element out of the tuple: `x[1]`.

You also have your condition incorrect. You are selecting the elements *with* extensions, not those *without*. Change `> 0` to `== 0`.

```
ras = [x for x in enumerate(rasters) if len(os.path.splitext(x[1])[1]) == 0]
```

This is assuming you intended to preserve the items' indices in the original list. If you didn't want that, you shouldn't have used `enumerate`.

```
ras = [x for x in rasters if len(os.path.splitext(x)[1]) == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `enumerate` from your list comprehension and and `not` in your if statement

```
ras = [x for x in rasters if not len(os.path.splitext(x)[1]) > 0]
```

`enumerate` will give you (index, value) list for rasters where as you need only values.

Also no need to check for length of `os.path.splitext(x)[1]` you can simply do

```
ras = [x for x in rasters if not os.path.splitext(x)[1]]
```

When used with if `bool` value of `os.path.splitext(x)[1]` will be considered which will be false for `''` strings.